# How to get t4 files to build in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, t4

When I build my c# solution the .tt files will not create the .cs file outputs. But if I right click the .tt files one at a time in solution explorer and select "Run Custom Tool" the .cs is generated, so the build tool setting is correct. What do I do to get the overall solution build to force the custom tool to run on the .tt files?

Comment: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/T4TextTemplateTransformationToolkitCodeGenerationBestKeptVisualStudioSecret.aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Paul, you can also generate code at build time with [TextTransform.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2015/modeling/generating-files-with-the-texttransform-utility?view=vs-2015) or [Elton Stoneman's MSBuild task](https://web.archive.org/web/20200803154046/http://geekswithblogs.net/EltonStoneman/archive/2008/07/25/an-msbuild-task-to-execute-t4-templates.aspx). Just keep in mind that behavior of the built-in directives, like [assembly](https://web.archive.org/web/20160720100512/http://www.olegsych.com:80/2008/02/t4-assembly-directive/) and [include](https://web.archive.org/web/20160708055150/http://www.olegsych.com:80/2008/02/t4-include-directive/) is different when T4 runs in Visual Studio vs. the command-line host.

Answer (score 5):

Answering my own question, they are supposed to be generated at design time as per this discussion:

https://web.archive.org/web/20081227142303/http://www.olegsych.com/2008/02/t4-template-directive/

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2017 (probably next versions too), you should add this in Pre-build event:

```
"$(DevEnvDir)TextTransform.exe" -out "$(ProjectDir)YourTemplate.cs" "$(ProjectDir)YourTemplate.tt"
```

p.s. The only solution that worked for me.

p.s.s. Change path to your template if it's located not in root project directory.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2013, I was able to get the .tt files to regenerate their targets by just adding these lines to the .csproj file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <!-- Get the Visual Studio version – defaults to 10: -->
  <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">10.0</VisualStudioVersion>
  <!-- Keep the next element all on one line: -->
  <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
</PropertyGroup>
<!-- To enable build tasks on your development computer, install Modeling SDK for Visual Studio. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40754 -->
<Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\TextTemplating\Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets" />
<!-- Run the Transform task at the start of every build -->
<PropertyGroup>
  <TransformOnBuild>true</TransformOnBuild>
</PropertyGroup>
<!-- Overwrite files that are read-only, for example because they are not checked out -->
<PropertyGroup>
  <OverwriteReadOnlyOutputFiles>true</OverwriteReadOnlyOutputFiles>
</PropertyGroup>
<!-- Transform every template every time -->
<PropertyGroup>
  <TransformOutOfDateOnly>false</TransformOutOfDateOnly>
</PropertyGroup>
```

However, for this to work, you'll need to have installed the [Modeling SDK for Visual Studio](https://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=40754).  I found all of this information, along with a more complete description of the options available, on this page: [Code Generation in a Build Process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee847423.aspx).