# T4 Templates - SubSonic 3 - Running at Build Time

Tags: .net, subsonic, code-generation, subsonic3, t4

How do you get the SubSonic 3 T4 templates to rerun prior to building in VS2008?
I don't have to continually "Run Custom Tool" on each one?

Answer (score 1):

Dupe: [How to get t4 files to build in visual studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405560/how-to-get-t4-files-to-build-in-visual-studio)

Oleg is the T4 guru, so his answer is probably as good as you'll get.