# Visual Studio ignores msbuild before.<solutionName>.sln.targets file

Tags: c#-4.0, visual-studio-2013, msbuild

My ultimate goal is to create a distribution folder when I build my solution that will contain all of the binaries and other required files whenever I build my solution.  I thought the best way to do this would be to add a before.solutionName.sln.targets file that will create these directories.  When I build the project using msbuild.exe and the command line the directory is created (from the before.targets file).  However, when I build from within visual studio the directory is not created.  And I have tried to close the solution and reopen it to make sure the solution has been reloaded.

Also, I know I can do this from a project file but since the solution contains multiple projects it doesnt make sense to have each solution create the required directories.  If I can get Visual Studio to use these .targets files instead I can reuse them in other projects with the same form.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I invoke my MSBuild Target when msbuild.exe starts and when it ends](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17709873/how-can-i-invoke-my-msbuild-target-when-msbuild-exe-starts-and-when-it-ends)

Comment: See: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/782934/visual-studio-not-executing-before-or-after-solution-file-targets

Comment: I guess the short answer is....not possible.  Should I update my question then to ask the best way to create a distributable directory for a solution in Visual Studio?