# How to skip projects a by flexible rule on build of a .sln file by MSBuild?

Tags: msbuild, windows-phone

I need to skip all projects which end to ".UnitTests" from build pipeline when I build it for ARM.

And I need to build it if I build for x86, but exclude other projects?

Is it possible to skip some projects from the build process by some kind of rules?

Comment: Interesting question, I'm also interested in an answer. Perhaps [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17712386/4534262) may help. Together with [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/177770/Creating-MSBuild-projects-from-sln-files).

Answer (score 2):

The msbuild way of doing this would be to use the `Configuration Manager` (`Build -> Configuration Manager`) in Visual Studio to map the projects to the solution config/platform.

In the `Configuration Manager`:

1. select `ARM` as the `Active Solution Platform` and uncheck `Build` for all the `*.UnitTests` projects and ensure the other projects have `Build` checked.
2. select `x86` as the `Active Solution Platform` check/uncheck `Build` based on which projects you want to build.

This will mean that whenever you build your solution for `Platform=ARM`, all the projects except for your `*.UnitTests`, will build. And similarly for `Platform=x86`.

You can read more about it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kkz9kefa.aspx).

Update:

If you need more custom logic to choose projects to build, then you could create a new top level build file like:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <ItemGroup Condition="'$(Platform)' == 'ARM'">
            <ARMProjects Include="abc\*.csproj" Exclude="**\*.UnitTests.csproj"/>
            <ARMProjects Include="def\*.csproj" Exclude="**\*.UnitTests.csproj"/>
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup Condition="'$(Platform)' == 'x86'">
         <!-- Create a group named X86Projects and select the projects as you need to -->
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="Build">
         <MSBuild Project="@(ARMProjects)" Targets="Build" Condition="'$(Platform)' == 'ARM'"/>
         <MSBuild Project="@(X86Projects)" Targets="Build" Condition="'$(Platform)' == 'x86'"/>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

Tweak the build targets or the projects selected according to your needs.

Comment: That's probably helpful advice for some readers, but that's the VS way of doing this, not the msbuild way of doing this.

Comment: I know it, but I'm looking for a way to change it on CI server on the fly instead of using static configurations.

Comment: @ViacheslavSmityukh On your CI server you could choose the configuration+platform to build via command line args: `msbuild /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=x86` . If you want more custom logic to choose the projects to build, then you can will need a custom msbuild file which does that for you. I will update the answer to include that.

Comment: @zeromus msbuild also supports the same thing. It parses the `.sln` file and generates a msbuild project file from that, based on the config+platform mappings found in the `.sln` file. You can select the config+platform for the build, from the command line.