# TextTransform.exe seems to only accept an older version of C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, command-line, c#-3.0, t4

When I expand T4 templates inside Visual Studio, I can use the full C# 3.0 syntax, including LINQ expressions, etc.  When I expand it outside Visual Studio using TextTransform.exe it complains about LINQ expressions and other new features of C# 3.0.  Is there a newer version of TextTransform.exe?

The one I'm running is in:

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\TextTemplating\1.2\TextTransform.exe
```

Comment: And no, there are no higher-numbered folders under TextTemplating

Comment: What form do these complaints take?

Comment: I would have to try it again to give you actual messages (not on that machine at the moment), but the gist is "I have no idea what you're trying to say".

Comment: I think "semicolon expected" was a popular "complaint".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.2 is the version of TextTransform that shipped with Visual Studio 2008. However, it will use C# compiler version 2.0 unless you specify version 3.5 in the [template](http://www.olegsych.com/2008/02/t4-template-directive/) directive. 3.5 is the internal version of the C# CodeDOM provider for C# 3.0 compiler.

Comment: It looks like the version directive may not be needed after all. In Visual Studio 2013 (and possibly VS2012) you get the following warning when you try to specify a version `The C# 2.0 and C# 3.5 compilers are no longer supported. Templates will always be compiled with the version 4 compiler instead of 'v3.5' as specified.`