# Where is TextTransform.exe Located on Hard drive?

Tags: t4

Where is TextTransform.exe located?

I'm trying to implement the solution in this post:
[Get Visual Studio to run a T4 Template on every build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646580/get-visual-studio-to-run-a-t4-template-on-every-build)

However I'm getting an error

"'TextTransform.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

I have been looking through the program files, however not sure where TextTransform.exe is located.

Comment: and Windows Search can't find it?

Comment: Windows search is slow and the results are always displayed weird.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be below

```
\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\TextTemplating\
```

see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126245.aspx

Comment: Cool, thanks for the link Chad.

I don't have VS2010, I have 2008. So the location for VS2008 is here:
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\TextTemplating\1.2

Comment: @Paul, same location here actually, which is why I took out the version from the URI

Comment: for Visual Studio 2010 it is in %Program Files (x86)%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\TextTemplating\10.0

Comment: For 2017 CE its here: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\TextTransform.exe"

Comment: Please refer to StingyJack s answer below regarding using vswhere.exe as it finds TextTransform.exe regardless of Visual Studio version.

Answer (score 6):

Anyone coming to this question that's using VS 2017 or later should be using vswhere to locate this file. @codingdave's comment is the closest but that still won't work on many computers.

I've added an example to the [Microsoft Docs article feedback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/generating-files-with-the-texttransform-utility?view=vs-2019) that shows how to do this with Powershell.

```
#the path to VSWhere.exe is always in programfiles(x86)

$progFilesx86Path = [System.Environment]::ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%programfiles(x86)%")
$vsWherePath = Join-Path $progFilesx86Path "\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe"

# this tells vswhere to use paths of the latest version of visual studio installed 
# to locate this exe anywhere in those paths, and return a single textual 
# value (not a json object or xml payload)

$ttExe = & $vsWherePath -latest -find **\TextTransform.exe -format value
if (-Not(Test-Path $ttExe)){
    throw "Could not locate TextTransform.exe"
}

#then to invoke a transformation
& "$ttExe"  c:\Source\YourTransform.tt
```

Comment: This is useful in msbuild, I set up a property `<_vsWhereExe Condition="!Exists('$(_TransformExe)')">$(ProgramFiles)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe</_vsWhereExe>` then used an exec task to output to a _TransformExe property which could then be used in a before build target. My previous msbuild setup used a cascading probe of absolute paths...

Answer (score 5):

From [@codingdave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1399018/codingdave)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3336752/1019435)
For VS2017, VS2019 location of TextTransform.exe will  be

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\<<Version>>\<<Edition>>\Common7\IDE`
Version -> (2017/2019/....)
Edition -> (Community/Professional/Enterprise)

And in pre build event we can use macro like
`"$(DevEnvDir)\TextTransform.exe" "$(ProjectDir)AssemblyInfo.tt"`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend trying this over that solution: http://www.olegsych.com/2010/04/understanding-t4-msbuild-integration

If you don't have VS 2010, though, I suppose you're stuck doing it the hard way.