# Error "A template containing a class feature must end with a class feature"

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors, t4

I was developing a C# T4 pre-processed template, under Visual Studio 2010, when I have got the following compilaton error:

> A template containing a class feature must end with a class feature

Comment: You really should post your solution as a stand-alone answer . It helped me a lot, thanks! However, I can have as many newline characters at the end as I wish, though. Only spaces seem to cause the issue for me.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The error is caused by an invisible space after the last **#>**

It is also important to bear in mind, that invisible spaces may cause other hard-to-understand compile-errors.

If you want to see a bigger picture, just look at following links:

- [A good example](http://hadsy.net/2011/05/17/CompilingTransformationInvalidTokenThisInClassStructOrInterfaceMemberDeclaration.aspx)
- [A good explanaton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5733739/378115), by [Ryan Pugh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/717538/ryan-pugh)

Now that you are aware how harmfull invisible spaces can be when dealing with Text Templates, my advice is: **Make them visible**. If you don't know how to do it, see [Jeef Widmer's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/jeffwids/archive/2009/11/11/how-to-show-white-space-in-visual-studio.aspx)