# Read a file compile-time in C#

Tags: c#, compilation

I am writing some unit tests in which I need a fake xml file. I can create that file and require it to be deployed with the unit tests, but experience shows that at my office it's a lot of headache. So I decided that the file will be created by UT's.

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(testFileName);
sw.Write(contents);
sw.Close();
```

Now the problem is the contents string. It is virtually a long xml, something like this:

```
string contents = 
@"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
  <blah>
  ~100 lines here
  </blah> ";
```

I don't want this to be in the same file as the rest of the code. I want the string to be generated compile-time from a file.

In C++, I'd do this

```
string contents = "
#include "test.xml"
   ";
```

Is it possible somehow in C#?

Comment: I think this has been asked before.

Comment: Wouldn't doing something like a `#include` require you to "create that file and require it to be deployed with the unit tests", the very thing you're trying to avoid?

Comment: @Fish: Of course not. It's compiled :))

Comment: Upvote because I'd never have dreamed that you could do that in C++ in the first place.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why don't you include it in a resource?

Comment: Ah! I had completely forgotten about those! :)

Comment: @Armen - it happens to the best of us.

Comment: Agreed, resource file sounds like the way to go.  Can open it with a stream and write it whereever you need to put it at runtime.

Comment: @Daniel, @Cortright: The resx file is compiled into the executable. Correct?

Comment: That's something else entirely Armen, you will want to google ".NET Embedded Resources"

Comment: Here's a link to get you started.  But yes, the resource will be 'embedded' in your executable when its compiled.  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/embeddedresources.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Use a resources (resx file) and add your xml file. Then you can access using MyNs.MyResources.MyXmlFile.

Comment: I don't need the resx file to be available runtime. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a T4 template.  What you need is 3 things

1. Create your template file, which will generate your .cs code
2. Include your text file (or *.sql file) in the same project as your template file
3. [Configure your template to re-create your t4 template on every build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646580/get-visual-studio-to-run-a-t4-template-on-every-build)

Something like this for your `template.tt` file

```
<#@ template debug="true" hostSpecific="true" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
<#@ Assembly Name="System.Core" #>
<#@ Assembly Name="System.Windows.Forms" #>
<#@ import namespace="System" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#
   string TextFromFile = File.ReadAllText(Host.ResolvePath("my_file_next_to_my_template.txt"));
#>
// This is the output code from your template
namespace MyNameSpace
{
    class MyGeneratedClass
    {
        static void main (string[] args)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("<#= TextFromFile #>");
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't want to configure your template to be re-created on the build then just opening it and saving it will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I usually add such test files directly into the unit test C# project and set them as "Content" and "Copy if newer" to be copied to the bin directory during the compilation.

Comment: The thing is that the exe is later taken from the bin and copied to a completely different machine and run there.

Comment: OK, then you'll need to add the file as an embedded resource, like others suggested.

Answer (score 0):

If the contents are static, why can't you commit it to source control? Add it to your project and then it will always be exactly where you expect it to be.

Comment: No, it won't. The unit test executables are copied to a different machine and run there

Comment: I see. I made the assumption that whatever you were using for continuous integration would be doing the whole build process. In that case, the resource answer already provided is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can go the resource file route but, depending on how many resources/how large they are (and XML can be large), you may eventually run into compilation problems (I did).

I've since transitioned from resources to singletons.  Reading a text file in with [File.ReadAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalltext.aspx) is pretty dead simple and it's still IntelliSense-friendly.

Comment: I want to avoid the necessity of the existence of the text file at runtime. With resources, AFAIK, my executable can run standalone with no external file dependency. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Armen: If you're running unit tests (which implies a development machine and access to source control), I don't know what the objection to having text files available is.  Your understanding is correct though - resources can be embedded in DLLs/executables.

Comment: At my office a special team deals with builds and UT runs. They build the trunk, then copy all UT executables to a separate machine and run the UT's there. I can request them not to forget to take my file as well, but I don't want to introduce that dependency

Answer (score 0):

I am currently writing a Blazor WASM app and I need to load GraphQL queries from files.
T4 templates do not feel appropriate to solve this issue, and neither do the other options.

I created a simple NuGet packege that leverages source generation to read files at compile time and return the contents from a method.

Take a look on Github: https://github.com/polferov/Polferov.StringFromFile

Disclaimer:
The development stage is "it works for me" and will likely stay that way.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35561714)