# How to programmatically control the Build Action of the new files generated from a T4?

Tags: c#, .net, templates, t4

The question is: is there a way to have a setting in the *.tt file so that the generated files are set to a specified Build Action?

The thing is I am generating code using a template, but it only meant to be a starting point, eliminating a lot of typing. I do not want anyone to use the code(generated classes) as is, nor I want it to clutter the namespace. Currently, I have to manually set the **Build Action to None** every time a new file being added by the template - **I would like to automate it.**

Thank you!

Comment: Here are some previous solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646580/get-visual-studio-to-run-a-t4-template-on-every-build

Answer (score 1):

A very simple workaround is to wrap the generated code into an `#if` statement:

```
#if GENERATED_CODE
    // my generated code
    // will compile only if the variable GENERATED_CODE is defined
#endif
```