# T4 Code template trigger generation on: other file save / xml change (VS 2010)

Tags: c#, .net, t4

I have a t4 template, that loops over an xml file in the project and genrate the code.
Is it possible to make the T4 to run when a certain file has bee saved, or when I build the project?
VS 2010

Thanks

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646580/get-visual-studio-to-run-a-t4-template-on-every-build/3381556#3381556 for enabling tranformation at build time in VS 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add the XML file to your project
2. Right Mouse button  on your xml file in your project solution explorer and view properties
3. Excluded from Build should say **No**
4. Item Type should say **Custom Build Tool**
5. Setup Custom Build Tool Command line and Outputs.

Now whenever the xml file changes (ie newer that its output) it will trigger a build. Rebuilding the project will also trigger a build.

Comment: Thanks, but how do i setup custom tool for this mission? its new for me, thanks

Comment: The custom tool can be a batch file. Pass $(InputPath) as argument to batch file. Create a simple batch file that does your T4 transformation and operates on the first argument to the batch file.

Comment: And how would such a batch file look like?

Answer (score 0):

Dynamo.AutoTT will do what you need.  You can configure it to watch files via a regex, and specify which T4 templates you want it to trigger.

You can download it from here : https://github.com/MartinF/Dynamo.AutoTT

Just build it, copy the dll and AddIn files into

C:\Users\\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Addins\

and away you go.

If you want to get it going in VS2012 you will need to modify the a Dynamo.AutoTT.AddIn file and set the Version to 11.0 inside the AddIn file;