# What's an efficient way to convert localized resources.resx files to javascript files in asp.net MVC?

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc-3, localization

I have localized resx files that I want to convert to JSON and store in js files (e.g. en-US.js).

What would be an efficient means of converting the resource files to javascript files at each build?

Comment: Just out of curiousity, why are you wanting to do this?

Comment: So that I can make use of the existing resx files in javascript, without manually maintaining both the resx files and the javascript files. I want to be able to load the file on the client once I have the user's culture and hand it off to some singleton js instance, or a utility like http://i18next.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a t4 template to parse it and output your js files. You could do this via a prebuild.

[Get Visual Studio to run a T4 Template on every build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646580/get-visual-studio-to-run-a-t4-template-on-every-build)

I would do this prebuild and then define a bundle to minify and bundle that folder using asp.net 4.5 bundling API or a third party tool like squishit or Minify etc.