# Generating T4 on Build using VS 2012

Tags: c#, .net, t4

I am trying to generate code on every build of my project using VS2012.

I have 3 projects in my solution :

- project 1 has some classes
- project 2 has the generic template
- project 3 has the template that read a json file and then call the generic template form project 2 to generate its file.

When I am clicking on Build/Transform All T4 Templates, there is no problem, the generation goes well.

But I am trying to configure my build to include this step automatically on every build.

I have added this code to my csproj :

```
<Import Project="$MsBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.Targets" />
<PropertyGroup>
   <TransformOnBuild>true</TransformOnBuild>
   <OverWriteReadOnlyOutputFiles>true</OverWriteReadOnlyOutputFiles>
</PropertyGroup>
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\TextTemplating\Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets"/>
```

I have made up  myself the path "*\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\TextTemplating\Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets*" from what I found on my pc.
The example I took it from was :[get-visual-studio-to-run-a-t4-template-on-every-build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646580/get-visual-studio-to-run-a-t4-template-on-every-build)

The problem comes from this line I am using  :
<#@ include file="$(SolutionDir)\xxx\yyy\zzz\mytemplate.tt">

and I receive the error :

> Failed to resolve include text for file :
>   D:\Projects\pppp\qqq\eeee\$(SolutionDir)\xxx\yyy\zzz\mytemplate.tt

As the template works well when it is generated "by hand" (Build/Transform All T4 Templates), I wonder what might be the problem for generating it at build time.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you are running your template during the build process it is being executed under different host and $(SolutionDir) macro does not exist. Try using relative path instead e.g.

```
<#@ include file="..\xxx\yyy\zzz\mytemplate.tt">
```

Comment: That could work with include but what about assembly? I used $(SolutionDir) to locate them, I have same kind of error If I try the relative path. The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. Thx for your help.

Comment: I finally used absolute path because anything else was working properly, and I needed to move on.

Comment: I'm not sure what was the problem with the relative path, but you can try `Host.ResolvePath` method

Comment: I solved this by defining an environment variable and using that in my path (e.g. `%EnvVar%\xxx\yyy\zzz\mytemplate.tt`).