# Error Generating T4 on Build using VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, template-engine, t4

I'm using **Visual Studio 2015 update 3**. I tried using *TextTransform.exe* with the **dp** flag, but I got this error :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Framework Tools\Templates\Includes\EF6.Utility.CS.ttinclude(1,4): error : A processor named 'T4VSHost' could not be found for the directive named 'CleanupBehavior'. The transformation will not be run.  The following Exception was thrown:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Failed to load directive processor T4VSHost. ---> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: L'index se trouve en dehors des limites du tableau.
 à Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.CommandLine.DirectiveProcessorConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)
 à Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.CommandLine.CommandLineHost.ResolveDirectiveProcessor(String processorName)
 à Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.CommandLine.CommandLineHost.ResolveDirectiveProcessor(String processorName)
 à  Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.Engine.ProcessCustomDirectives(ITextTemplatingEngineHost host, TemplateProcessingSession session, IEnumerable`1 directivesToBeProcessed)
```

Line that generated the error :

```
 texttransform -out "P:\<Path to project>\Model.cs" -I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Framework Tools\Templates\Includes" -dp T4VSHost"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.dll" "P:\<Path to project>\Model.tt"
```

Other issues I looked up :

- [Get Visual Studio to run a T4 Template on every build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646580/get-visual-studio-to-run-a-t4-template-on-every-build) (I used the accepted answer as a base)
- [Processor Named ‘T4VSHost’ Could Not Be Found For The Directive Named ‘CleanupBehavior’](https://romiller.com/2013/03/21/processor-named-t4vshost-could-not-be-found-for-the-directive-named-cleanupbehavior/)
- [Generating T4 on Build using VS 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12801927/generating-t4-on-build-using-vs-2012) (not as flexible as a batch file)

What I know so far is that all paths are correct and that T4VSHost's definition in my registry is correct.

Restrictions :

- I cannot modify/move the .tt files
- I cannot move assembly files or the ttinclude file (though I tried)

I would very much like to avoid modifying the EF.CS.ttinclude file. What could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-dp` switch is missing the class name, it should have name, full type name, and assembly of the directive processor.

Directive processor syntax:

```
-dp &lt;processorName&gt;!&lt;className&gt;!&lt;assemblyName|codeBase&gt;
```

[For `EF6.Utility.CS.ttinclude` specifically, it needs `T4VSHost` for `CleanupBehavior`, which is located in `Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.dll`](https://romiller.com/2013/03/21/processor-named-t4vshost-could-not-be-found-for-the-directive-named-cleanupbehavior/):

Directive processor for CleanupBehavior:

```
-dp T4VSHost!Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VisualStudio.Directives.FallbackT4VSHostProcessor!"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.dll"
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I have passed the issue to someone else, but I'll try and see if it does solve it.