# Why does forfiles swallow the first argument of the command?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to do something similar to [Get Visual Studio to run a T4 Template on every build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646580) using cmd's `forfiles` to transform each template in VS2008.

If I execute

```
forfiles /m "*.tt" /s /c "\"%CommonProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Shared\TextTemplating\1.2\TextTransform.exe\" @file"
```

then I get `TextTransform.exe`'s error message (the screen of text explaining what to pass it as arguments).

If I instead execute

```
forfiles /m "*.tt" /s /c "cmd /c echo Transforming @path && \"%CommonProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Shared\TextTemplating\1.2\TextTransform.exe\" @file"
```

then it works perfectly.

In order to debug this, I created a simple command-line program called `debugargs` which simply prints the number of arguments it receives and their values. Then some experimentation shows that the first form of directly passing the command to `forfiles` causes the first argument to be swallowed. E.g.

```
forfiles /m "*.tt" /s /c "debugargs.exe 1 2 3"
```

gives output

```
2 arguments supplied
#1: 2
#2: 3
```

The [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753551.aspx) I've been able to find is quite sparse, and I don't see any mention of this as a possibility. Is it just an obscure bug, or am I missing something?

Comment: Interesting.  All the samples I see online use `/c "cmd /c ..."`; none of them call a separate exe directly.

Comment: Strange. I found that if EITHER of the first 2 parameters is an EXE then that EXE will run and receive the remaining arguments (ie param3+) If however the args are .BATs, then the SECOND will run, receiving params 3+

Comment: @PeterWright, interesting observation. It seems to be slightly more complicated. Looking only at cases where the second parameter is an `exe`: if the first parameter isn't a file, I get `ERROR: The system cannot find the file specified.`. If the first parameter is e.g. a text file I get `ERROR: "test.txt" is not a valid executable.` So the only dummy which really works there is an existing `.bat` or `.cmd` file. Bizarre.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in the way `forfiles` invokes `.exe`s. On a hunch I extended my `debugargs` program to print the full command line.

```
X:\MyProject>forfiles /m "*.tt" /s /c "debugargs.exe 1 2 @file"

2 arguments supplied
#1: 2
#2: Urls.tt
Full command line: 1 2 "Urls.tt"
```

So the most appropriate workaround would be to double the executable name:

```
forfiles /m "*.tt" /s /c "debugargs.exe debugargs.exe 1 2 @file"
```

The alternative workaround is to invoke with `cmd /c`. However, note here that if you need to quote the executable's path (e.g. because it contains a space), you'll need an extra workaround of prepending `@`:

```
forfiles /m "*.tt" /s /c "cmd /c @\"debugargs.exe\" 1 2 @file"
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the `@` character here?  I wanted to use the `FORFILES` with an executable's path containing spaces and couldn't manage to make it work.  It's like the `@` character enabled the use of the `\"` which I already tried but without the `@` and without success.  Is there a place where I could have more information about this property?  Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I can't remember. I don't use cmd at all often: for preference I use cygwin bash.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced the behavior in forfiles as well. You can work around by using cmd /c before the command, or you could transition to PowerShell, where the equivalent command would be something like this (not tested):

```
get-childitem . -filter "*.tt" -recurse | foreach-object {
  & "${ENV:CommonProgramFiles(x86)}\Microsoft Shared\TextTemplating\1.2\TextTransform.exe" "`"$($_.Name)`""
}
```

Bill

Comment: I don't think PowerShell is an option (unless I invoke it from `cmd`), because VS2008 dumps the command I give it into a batch file to execute.

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this as well. The work-around I've found is to just add an extra space between the command and first argument! So where I was trying to do:

```
FORFILES /s /m *.dll /c "python \"c:\path\to\script.py\" -t arg1 etc"
```

python was trying to find file "arg1" to execute, but if I just change it to:

```
FORFILES /s /m *.dll /c "python  \"c:\path\to\script.py\" -t arg1 etc"
```

this actually works!