# How to automatically substitute string at compile time (C# DLL)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build, visual-studio-2013

I am compiling a DLL using Visual Studio 2013 and for technical reasons cannot use `System.Version` since it is not supported in one of my target runtime environments.

Is there a way to automatically place the assembly "FileVersion" into a constant at compile-time?

```
public const string MyFileVersion = "{{ PLEASE REPLACE ME }}";
```

I am not using a build server or anything fancy like that, just Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: You can use [#ifdev](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288458(v=vs.71).aspx) and set compile variables.

Comment: @Dmitry Can it automatically update from the assembly file version? I don't want to have maintenance hell where I forget to keep multiple versions updated...

Comment: This is a clear chicken-and-egg problem.  You need an oracle that knows what the next version number needs to be.  You'll have to provide one, write your own program to modify a small .cs file that contains the attribute and modify it by whatever rules you like.  Run it in a prebuild event.  Do keep in mind that [AssemblyFileVersion] is pretty useless, the CLR completely ignores it.  It is just annotational, you see it back in the Details tab when you look at the file properties.  That's all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like t4 templates could help you. It's [template generation engine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx). There are enough info about it which will be helpful.

I made a simple template which does what you want. It's just an example and probably you need to make some adjustments in the code:

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="true" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ assembly name="Microsoft.CSharp.dll" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text.RegularExpressions" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Reflection" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>

<#
        var assemblyVersionRegex = new Regex(@"AssemblyVersion\(\""(?<version>(.*?))\""\)");
        var pathBase = new FileInfo(Host.TemplateFile).DirectoryName;
        var assemblyInfoPath = Path.Combine(pathBase, @"Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs");

        var assemblyInfoSources = File.ReadAllText(assemblyInfoPath);
        var match = assemblyVersionRegex.Match(assemblyInfoSources);
        var version = match.Success 
                ? match.Groups["version"].Value
                : "unknow";
#>

public static class SomeAssemblyInfo
{
    public const string Version = "<#= version #>";
}
```

So, it reads file AssemblyInfo.cs (or another if you want) get version from it and prepare class SomeAssemblyInfo :

```
public static class SomeAssemblyInfo
{
    public const string Version = "1.0.0.0";
}
```

Last thing what you need to do is run this template on build. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646580/get-visual-studio-to-run-a-t4-template-on-every-build) you can find how to do it.

Comment: This looks like it might be the answer, though I am getting an error: "Error 62 Compiling transformation: The name 'Host' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: @LeaHayes, have you set hostspecific="true" at the first line

Comment: My bad, I accidentally pasted the same line twice. This works perfectly! You are a lifesaver :)

Comment: I had to change the template a little since I needed "FileVersion", but this was straightforward.

Comment: @LeaHayes yes, this is just idea, and how you get the version is up to you. You can load already compiled assembly, or make a web request. no matter