# Autoupdate .tt file in Visual Studio to generate revision number

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, build

I have a .tt file which generates my projects build and revision number. The number is regenerated every time the file is saved or run. Is there a way to configure pre build commands to do this automatically ?

If possible without installing other SDKs or third party software.

Comment: See [Code Generation in a Build Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee847423.aspx).

Comment: Thhis procedure needs the intallation of the modeling sdk... a thing I would like to avoid if possible. But thank your for the suggestion

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Visual Studio to run a T4 Template on every build](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646580/get-visual-studio-to-run-a-t4-template-on-every-build)