# EF code first: Generate pre-compiled view (VS 13 express)

Tags: entity-framework, code-first, precompiled-views

I have an application using EF code first. Unfortunately the first query takes an awful lot of time to load. When I goggled, I realized this is a quite common problem. Obviously EF needs to init/generate some views in order to work properly.

To speed this up, it's possible to generate pre-compiled views. But all solutions I found use the EF Power Tools. Unfortunately it's not possible to install the Power Tools in VS Express, at least I haven't found a way (please correct me if I'm wrong).

Is there any way to generate the views without the power tools?
(maybe command line?)

Ciao,
Dante

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. The actual logic to create the views is not part of EF PowerTools, but part of EF itself. EF PowerTools merely provides a nice easy-to-use menu item for it.

There are a few approaches you can take, but probably the simplest is to use a T4 template. The ADO.NET Blog has [an entry on this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2008/06/20/how-to-use-a-t4-template-for-view-generation.aspx), but there are newer ready-to-use templates available online from the VS gallery, such as [this one](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/18a7db90-6705-4d19-9dd1-0a6c23d0751f); you may need to tweak it or look for a different one if you're not using EF6 though. Templates should install and work in any version of Visual Studio, even the Express editions, but should you encounter difficulties, as a last resort it should always be possible to unpack the downloaded file (it's a zip file) and copy the required file into your project manually.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I finally managed to install the template (had some problems with my VS installation, but should probably work for others). So I added the template to my project, the view generation was successful. 
But how do I use the view? Is it somehow called automatically by some magic?

Comment: @dante Yes, Entity Framework uses reflection to search the context's assembly's attributes for where the pre-generated views can be found, so the magic is activated by the `[assembly: System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.MappingViews.DbMappingViewCacheTypeAttribute(...)]` line in the template output.

Comment: Is there a way to automate the view regeneration when the model changes? Perhaps via a pre-build event or similar?

Comment: @Zero3 I have no experience with that, but [apparently there are options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646580/get-visual-studio-to-run-a-t4-template-on-every-build).