# How to create ENUM using values from the database C#

Tags: c#, enums

I have a status table in database whose values I am using across the application. Status Table will have (ID, NAME). I want to create a StatusEnum which I can use in my code in the application. How can I create ENUM using values from database ?

Currently I have enum like this

```
enum StatusCode: int
{
    Open = 20,
    Received = 21,
    Delivered= 22,
    Cancelled = 23
}
```

But I want to set the values from database.

Comment: Look into T4 to generate the source file with the enums defined. They'll be available to you at compile time.

Comment: You do realise this has to be done *before* you compile the program? Any changes in the database after the program has been compiled will not appear in the program. If you later add a `PendingPayment` value in the database, the program will still only have the 4 from before. Since these are in effect *magical values* of your program, I would instead make sure the database was updated with what the program required, instead of the other way around.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I think that this can be done only manually. Am I wrong? I have posted an answer, but since I got a downvote I deleted it. Thank you very much for your response in advance.

Comment: When you set those types of tables in the database, they have to be tables that you don't touch. If you have to add something, then it's a new release version of your software. (Also, you don't need to derive your `enum` from `int`. All enums are able to number the values.)

Comment: You can use a T4 template as @JeroenVannevel commented, and you can add some trickery to have it executed on every build, see here for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646580/get-visual-studio-to-run-a-t4-template-on-every-build

Comment: Why do you need the values in the database in the first place? Do you want to allow to dynamically update them? Will alter and recompile your application each time a user changes anything to the Status Table?

Comment: @krillgar The fact that enums are able to set values for their members is true. However, if OP didn't set explicitly that Open=20, Open would have been equal to 0.

Comment: @Christos That's not what he said. He only said the OP doesn't need this: `: int`.

Comment: Right. but he doesn't have to derive his enum from int to get that effect. The contents of his enum are correct. I wasn't saying anything about that.

Comment: @krillgar oops I am sorry :). I read very fast your comment and I made a fault. You are correct. I was wrong.

Comment: @YannickMotton there is no possibility that application will be compiled when status table gets updated.. value needs to be updated dynamically from db.. if it's static I can have them in config file.

Comment: @msbyuva are these values local to your application, or are you consuming a 3rd party data source?

Comment: @YannickMotton they r local to my app which comes from DB.

Comment: @msbyuva If your application is owner of the data, see my answer below. Just define the enum members and assign integer values (like you did in your question), and either upcast their persisted form (an integer) as per my sample code, either when using an ORM you get this for free.

Comment: @YannickMotton I am doing the same but was looking for something dynamically. Don't want to make it complex, I will go with what I am doing that is from your answer first option..

Comment: @msbyuva Ask yourself what the *point* would be to have database values, that can be change independently from your application, but are represented as constant values in code? An Enum is just a friendly representation of a *magic* value, on you which typically have some sort of conditional logic. Would you want their semantic meaning to change without you re-evaluating your code? If they're actually dynamic, and you don't use them in logic, just represent them as strings in the database?

Answer (score 1):

You can

- Manually keep your enum definition in sync with the database. This is the easiest way.
- You could [write a single file generator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166817.aspx) for Visual Studio (also known as a ["Custom Tool"](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/686405/Writing-a-Single-File-Generator)) and have that generate the enum definition from some reference database. Single File Generators take some source file (e.g., *.aspx) and from it generate code (e.g. *.designer.cs). Very useful to be able to do this.
- A third technique would be a hermaphrodite variant of the preceding two techniques: write a stand-alone tool to generate your enum definitions from the database. Run the tool against your reference DB to regenerate the file and check it back in.

Either way, you can't change the lookup tables in the database will-nilly without affecting your application. Newly-added values will be unknown to the app; removed or changed values will likely break things.

But presumably, the sorts of things you would want an enum for are all relatively stable sorts of things.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to attempt an answer.

If the idea is that you have magic numbers in your database, which are `const` in nature, meaning they rarely change, I can see why you would want to represent them as something readable in code.

Depending on how you would query the data, there are different ways of representing this data as an enum value:
For a `SqlDataReader` just upcast the integer value coming from the record to the enum:

```
int statusCodeValue = row["status"];
// But BEWARE as undefined values also upcast to the enum just fine
// but just won't have any of the defined values
if (!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(StatusCode), statusCodeValue)) throw new Exception();
StatusCode statusCode = (StatusCode)statusCodeValue;
```

If you're using an ORM like nHibernate or EF, you get this mapping out of the box. Just define the enum property on your data model, and it will correctly map.

### Note

You need to think about who is the owner of the data. Is this data coming from another system, or does your application generate it?

If it's foreign, you'll need to keep the data and your application enum in sync manually.
If it's local, just make sure to assign an integer value to each enum member, and never change that integer value from what it should semantically represent.

Comment: I should note that this presents a potential hazard, should any out-of-band data manipulations be required (and if you work with a system long enough, they will be).  If a non-defined enum value is entered into the table, the next time the front-end tries to display the row, it will throw an exception.  While it might *be* exceptional, this is the kind of exception that database constraints are made for.  And the only reasonable way (I can think of) to build that database constraint (and keep it in sync with the enum during development) is manually, or to build either with code-gen...

Answer (score -1):

You really can't do this.  You will need some helper functions to help you along.

```
enum StatusCode
{
   Open,
   Received,
   Delivered,
   Cancelled
}

private Dictionary<StatusCode, int> storedCodes = new Dictionary<StatusCode, int>();

public static int GetValue(StatusCode code)
{
    //Return code from database
    return storedCodes[code];
}

public static void SetValue(StatusCode code, int value)
{
    storedCodes[code] = value;
    //Set values from database
    //Note:  you can't set the value of your enums here
    //Just a place to set some other variables to remember what the values are.
}
```

Comment: your answer is not understandable for me.. from your example where do I assign the value to ENUM ? I know how to get values from db & save/hold them to an object.. Question is how I populate/load/assign those values to Enum

Comment: You can use a dictionary object to store the values.  Are you planning on having it dynamic without building a new application when a status value change.

Answer (score -1):

What you are asking is technically possible with text templating (an example is after the fold).  However, as has been pointed out, good text templating isn't easy and usually requires just as much maintenance as your application code.

Instead, take a look and determine whether your Enum is *really* a constrained list of all possible states.  If you are storing your statuses in a database table, I would say that it is not.  Being in a table makes it technically possible that these values will change (new ones can be inserted, old ones deleted or even the names changed such that they no longer reflect their original meaning).  Only user convention will prevent this, and it won't be immediately apparent in your application code.

You might be better off rethinking your database design.  The next statement is tricky for me to explain, but I prefer not to infer entity status based on a child relationship.  Instead I prefer to make code decisions based individual column value of a given data row.

For example, rather than two tables, as per:

```
CREATE TABLE status_codes (
  key INT PRIMARY KEY, 
  value VARCHAR(32)
);
CREATE TABLE entity (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY, 
  name VARCHAR(32), 
  status INT 
  CONSTRAINT fk_status FOREIGN KEY status REFERENCES status_codes(id)
);
INSERT INTO status_codes 
VALUES (20, 'Open')
      ,(21, 'Received')
      ,(22, 'Delivered')
      ,(23, 'Cancelled');
```

I would prefer:

```
CREATE TABLE entity (
  id INT,
  name VARCHAR(32),
  is_received BIT NOT NULL,
  is_delivered BIT NOT NULL,
  is_cancelled BIT NOT NULL,
  is_closed BIT NOT NULL
);
```

For me, I find it easier to code the logic when there are no magic numbers.

This way you are no longer doing things like:

```
/* SQL */
SELECT * FROM entity WHERE status = 20;

/* C# */
if (entity.Status == StatusCodes.Open) { /* do something */ }
if (entity.Status == 20) { /* do something */ }
```

and instead doing:

```
/* SQL */
SELECT * FROM entity WHERE is_closed = 0;

/* C# */
if (!entity.IsClosed) { /* do something */ }
```

You can also employ database constraints for process (e.g. ensuring an item cannot be marked received before it is delivered, and cannot be cancelled if it has already been delivered).

I've also changed 'is open' semantics to 'is closed', but that is just a personal preference to make doing something (i.e. closing) be more significant than not done anything (i.e. is open).

I also note that sometimes you do need 'soft', user-maintainable states for things.  However, I would suggest that these should be for display purposes only and that you shouldn't write 'hard' code around these 'soft' states.

(If your application is intended to be a highly-customisable, off-the-shelf product, you might look at making soft states available to a scripting or rules engine, so the users who define the states can also define the business rules around them, but this is well outside of scope.)

---

With all that said, if you really, really feel that you need to do what you are asking, one possible approach is below...

Firstly, you need a canonical source for your enum values.  Either your C# Enum is correct, or the SQL definition is correct.

Once this is decided, I would probably use some form of text templating, like T4 or a custom script file/compiled exe to generate the one that *isn't* the canonical source.

### C# code is canonical

Reflect your Enum using `Enum.GetValues(typeof(StatusCode))` and `Enum.GetName(typeof(StatusCode), value)`, then use this to generate a `CHECK` constraint in your target table.  Store the base `int` type in your database table (e.g. `ALTER TABLE my_table ADD status_code INT`).

```
// (untested, pseudo-ish code -- WATCH FOR INJECTION!)

StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
sql.Append(@"ALTER TABLE [my_table] ADD CONSTRAINT chk_status_code CHECK (status_code IN (");

bool first = true;
foreach (var v in Enum.GetValues(typeof(StatusCode)) {
    if (!first) sql.Append(", ");
    sql.Append(v);
    first = false;
}

sql.Append("));");

// write sql to file, or run against the development database
```

This would get you very close to a SQL statement that could be run on build / install.  Note that this is not intended to be run during the normal operation of your database.

If you need the functionality, you may also want to generate an inline table function to map number to name, e.g.:

```
// (untested, pseudo-ish code -- WATCH FOR INJECTION!)

StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
sql.AppendLine(@"IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.tf_status_codes') IS NULL EXECUTE('
                     CREATE FUNCTION dbo.tf_status_codes RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN (
                         SELECT ''not yet built'' AS err
                     )
                 ')");
sql.AppendLine(@"ALTER FUNCTION dbo.tf_status_codes RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN (")
   .AppendLine(@"  SELECT value, name FROM (VALUES ")

bool first = true;
foreach (var v in Enum.GetValues(typeof(StatusCode)) {
    if (!first) sql.AppendLine(",");
    sql.Append(@"    ({0}, '{1}')", 
               v,
               Enum.GetName(typeof(StatusCode), v));
    first = false;
}

sql.AppendLine(@"  ) e(value, name);")
   .AppendLine(@")";

// write sql to file, or run against the development database
```

Run the build tool as a Post-Build event, so the code is updated before the constraint / table.

### SQL table is canonical

This one is more straight-forward, although I would make sure that the table source cannot change during the lifetime of the production iteration (i.e. only defined at deployment time).  For this, I would define my enum values as an inline table function, rather than a table:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.status_codes 
RETURNS TABLE 
AS RETURN (
    SELECT value, name
    FROM (VALUES (20, 'Open')
                ,(21, 'Received')
                ,(22, 'Delivered')
                ,(23, 'Cancelled')) AS v(value, name)
)
```

Then, in my build tool, connect to the database, retrieve the values and generate the enum:

```
// untested, pseudo, assumes an existing database connection routine 
IDataReader reader = DB.GetReader("SELECT value, name FROM dbo.status_codes()");

StringBuilder code = new StringBuilder();
code.AppendLine("namespace MyApp {")
    .AppendLine("  public enum StatusCodes : int {");

bool first = true
while (reader.Read()) {
    if (!first) code.AppendLine(",");
    code.Append("    {0} = {1}", reader["name"], reader["value"]);
    first = false;
}

code.AppendLine("  }")
    .AppendLine("}");

// ...write the code to the Enum class file, and exit with 0 code
```

Run the build tool as a Pre-Build event (so the code is generated before it is built).

**(As I said, the code above is untested and no attempt has been made to secure it for injection.  Use at your own risk and test *thoroughly*)**

Comment: My feeling when reading your answer is one I get all too often: this is how an irrelevant problem gets a solution which people will be scratching their heads for in about a week.