# OrmLite - does not generate poco files

Tags: c#, t4, ormlite-servicestack

I am new to T4. I need to generate default sheema for my db by using ServiceStack.OrmLite.T4. I installed Install-Package ServiceStack.OrmLite.T4 and added app.config to my project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <add name="SqlClient Data Provider" 
         invariant="System.Data.SqlClient" 
         description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SqlServer" 
         type="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientFactory, System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Default" 
       connectionString="Data Source=(local)\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True;Initial Catalog=TestDb;" 
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Then I rebuild the project and nothing happens. Why the cs files would not created?

Answer (score 1):

The T4 templates will not be processed on each build unless you [explicitly configure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646580/get-visual-studio-to-run-a-t4-template-on-every-build) it to do so.

Normally you have to save the T4 file in Visual Studio or run the templating tool by right clicking the file in the Solution Explorer and selecting Run Custom Tool.