# C#: How to read file at compile-time

Tags: c#

Suppose I have a text file (such as a SQL query) stored in my Visual Studio project.  Is there any way I can save the file's contents to a variable **at compile time**?  I just want to have some text in its own file, instead of having a really long quoted string in my source code; but I don't want the hassle of having to deploy (or keep track of) the file.

Comment: Really at compile time and not run-time?

Comment: Compile-time would mean you want the contents of that file compiled into your source code. Run-time would be: ok, I need to run this query, read it out of the file and run it. Which is it you're after?

Comment: Embed as a resource and use it when needed...

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ but you could still just read the file at run-time and just save the query in memory for later and not necessarily execute it right away... that's why I asked, a little confused.

Comment: How about just putting your text/query in a resource file and access it from there?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a T4 template.  What you need is 3 things

1. Create your template file, which will generate your .cs code
2. Include your text file (or *.sql file) in the same project as your template file
3. [Configure your template to re-create your t4 template on every build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646580/get-visual-studio-to-run-a-t4-template-on-every-build)

Something like this for your `template.tt` file

```
<#@ template debug="true" hostSpecific="true" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
<#@ Assembly Name="System.Core" #>
<#@ Assembly Name="System.Windows.Forms" #>
<#@ import namespace="System" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#
   string TextFromFile = File.ReadAllText(Host.ResolvePath("my_file_next_to_my_template.txt"));
#>
// This is the output code from your template
namespace MyNameSpace
{
    class MyGeneratedClass
    {
        static void main (string[] args)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("<#= TextFromFile #>");
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't want to configure your template to be re-created on the build then just opening it and saving it will do the trick.