# Include another t4 template dynamically

Tags: c#, t4

I'm working with t4 templates and faced with following problem. I need include another existing t4 template to my template. But I have one restriction: name of included t4 template file is generated dynamically.
I used `include` directive for this, but it doesn't work.

```
<#@ include file="\Helpers\<# FileName.tt#>" #>
```

I get an error:

```
 An unexpected start or end tag was found within a block. Make sure that you did not mis-type a start or end tag, and that you do not have any nested blocks in the template.
```

Value of property `FileName` is generated dynamically

Comment: Why would you generate T4? I can not think of any scenerio where the additonal step makes sense.

Comment: @Toxantron,I have a few t4 template files. And depends on situation I should include one of them to my template. But which one will be included is determined by config file.

Comment: Have you tried? `<#@ include file=string.Format(@"\Helpers\{0}.tt", FileName) #>`

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't help.

Comment: I think there is no way to use include here, because the way I see it, include is resolved at compile time. Is it a runtime template?

Comment: Yes, my case is a runtime template

Comment: In this case the rules of OO design apply. Each template is just a class and you can use the objects with interface etc. to do that.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use a parameter, you need to setup msbuild property (say in the BeforeBuild target) or pass to msbuild as /p:TargetPath="[path]", and you can use them with the following:

```cs
<#@ include file="$(TargetPath)\TargetFile.tt" #>
```

(more information on [MSBuild properties usage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171458.aspx) here)

Additionally, you can configure t4 templates to run on each build

```xml
<!-- This line could already present in file. If it is so just skip it  -->
<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
<!-- process *.tt templates on each build  -->
<PropertyGroup>
    <TransformOnBuild>true</TransformOnBuild>
</PropertyGroup>
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\TextTemplating\v10.0\Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets" />
```

... as mentioned here: [Get Visual Studio to run a T4 Template on every build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646580/get-visual-studio-to-run-a-t4-template-on-every-build)