# c# replace tokens in files on build

Tags: c#, replace, build, token

I have a .net core console app in VS19 for a browser extension.

The project includes a couple of `.manifest` and `.reg` files which have different values for each target configuration (Dev, Test, Prod).

I'd like to have one template file for each `.manifest`, `.reg` file having tokens instead of those values and replace them with the real values (stored e.g. in appsettings.json) after building the solution (keeping my template file untouched).

What is the simples way to achieve this?

Comment: The **simplest** way would be to have not one template but 3 sources for your build targets and use a target configuration post-build task to add the one for the specific environment. Of course the downside is to keep 3 sources up to date.

Comment: Well, this is my current situation but as you mentioned it is a bit cumbersome for I already have 9 files and an additional target configuration on the brink.

Comment: There's [T4 templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/code-generation-in-a-build-process?view=vs-2019) and [How to run them on build](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1646580/205233) but I'm pretty sure this is way beyond *simple*.

Comment: Thanks, I hope there is sg simplier :)